# How to validate part of message in WSOESB and choose first?

Tags: wso2-esb

Here is how it works.
I do have dss service that returns message of format

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dss="https://rmis33.r-mis.ru/services/dss">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dss:Requests>
          <dss:Request>...</dss:Request>
          <dss:Request>...</dss:Request>
          <dss:Request>...</dss:Request>
           ....
          <dss:Request>...</dss:Request>
      </dss:Requests>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have to split message on Request element and validate it, then choose first that pass validation over XSD.

It is hard to do on database level because it has a lot of elements(sub-elements) and XSD was already provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [validate mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Validate+Mediator) to validate XML messages against XML schema.There is a complete [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+7%3A+Using+Schema+Validation+and+the+Usage+of+Local+Registry+for+Storing+Configuration+Metadata) which demonstrates validating messages.